# equivalent to 'from the page 100'

Tags: phrase-requests

We use the phrase 'from the page 100'. It means like from the end, without any details and say the most important thing straight away. It is not like 'I'll cut to the chase' or 'in short' or 'make a long story short'. 
Because it can be used in these contexts:
- come to me from the page 100. 
- from the page 100, I did it.
Etc.

It's kind of more flexible than the phrases in english.  I'm asking for if there is anything as flexible and quick. When it said in arabic, it's said quick, the aforementioned english ones seem too long for me.

Comment: The current version is TL;DR. But I'm not sure why "cut to the chase" is "too long". Seems pretty quick to me.

Comment: Or "long story short", for that matter... Most of the time I hear it used, the two sayings are shortened as I have done.

Comment: Why is "come to me from the page 100" more flexible or quick than "cut to the chase"? Why is "from the page 100, I did it" more flexible or quick than "in short, I did it"?

Comment: I think you should translate it as "from page 100", because "page 100" does not take a definite article in English.

Comment: The way you describe this (from the end, without any details and say the most important thing straightaway) is exactly what is meant by "cut to the chase". To _[come/get] to the point_. To _get to the crux of the matter_. To _get down to the nitty-gritty_.

Answer (score 3):

'The bottom line'? It's a business term regarding financial statements, but it's usable in all types of situations personal and professional.

"What's the bottom line?"

"Well, the bottom line is ..."

Does this help?